# Haversine formula in Hibernate - Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Haversine Formula

```
SELECT 
   id, 
  (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) 
    - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I tried to write using Hibernate:

```
String query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lng ) - radians(-?) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VehicleDetails Vehicle HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";

Object[] params  = {lat,lng};

List<VehicleDetails> vehicledata = getHibernateTemplate().find(query,params);
```

> Exception: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `group by` clause, you don't need a `having` clause, you can use `where`. I believe the error is due to the * in the first select, you might want to rewrite as

```
SELECT Vehicle.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lng ) - radians(-?) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VehicleDetails Vehicle where distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20"
```

Comment: Pradeep, I have updated the query and this is the error I got - 

**Exception:** 

'org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found * near line 1, column 17 [SELECT Vehicle.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) * cos( radians( Vehicle.lng ) - radians(-?) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( Vehicle.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM com.app.account.VehicleDetails Vehicle where distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20]'